# Where can I get real-time stock price data for National Stock Exchange of India (NSE)?

Tags: stock-exchanges, online-data-source, real-time-quotes, nse-india

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, however I couldn't find a better place after searching Stack Exchange.

From where can I get **tick data/real-time data** for the National Stock Exchange of India (NSE)? I am willing to pay a sober price for the data, but I cannot afford data providers like Bloomberg or eSignal.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. After extensive searching I couldn't find any good source.

Answer (score 2):

The data from NSE is provided by NSE for a charge of around Rs 2,00,000 to 10,00,000. The details are at http://www.nseindia.com/supra_global/content/dotex/data_products.htm

As most of the brokers / websites would be paying for the data, I am not sure if someone would give this at a cheaper price to individual.

Depending on the need, you may write a screen scraper to get data from site like MoneyControl.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the StockViz API on [mashape](https://www.mashape.com/drona/stockviz#!endpoint-Live-Price-Equity). It's a delayed by roughly 10-15min but has tick-level data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open an account with a broker in India that provides streaming data, you can get data streaming into Excel for around $60 - $120 per month.

Comment: could you please provide the url of the broker