# Getting live data from Yahoo! Finance for the National Stock Exchange of India (NSE)?

Tags: stock-exchanges, online-data-source, real-time-quotes, yahoo-finance, nse-india

Refer to [Streaming real-time stock quotes from Yahoo! Finance](http://billing.finance.yahoo.com/realtime_quotes/signup?.src=quote&.refer=quote)

Can I get real time data (from NSE India) using Yahoo! Finance API after subscribing to their service ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get real-time stock price data for National Stock Exchange of India (NSE)?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10857/where-can-i-get-real-time-stock-price-data-for-national-stock-exchange-of-india)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think so.  If you read the list of features listed on the page you referred to, notice:

> Track Stocks
>
> - Manage your portfolio(s) by selecting from over 50 criteria
> - 3 exchanges: **NYSE, NASDAQ, and AMEX** *[emphasis mine]*
> - Manipulate data better

It looks like it is restricted to the major U.S. stock markets.  No mention of India's NSE.